# numpy value shows same id result after changing the assigned value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question.(python version : 3.9.7)
I run this below code. However, I cannot understand this happening.
plz, let me know why it happens below.
(As far as I know, number is immutable, so when something new as a number is assigned, the object address should point out different address including the number.)

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])

id(a[0]) #1977043162384*


A = [0,0,0]; a[0] = A

id(a[0]) #1977043162384 (I cannot understand this part)***

b = [1,2,3]

a[0] = b

id(a[0]) #1977290465808
```

The ID number on Line 4 should be changed, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why should it be changed? You understand, every time you access an array Python *create a new object*, correct?

Comment: Just run the program several times, sometimes it will print different ids others same id. It doesn't mean that it is only updating the address.

Comment: `id` if virtually useless when indexing arrays.  Arrays are not lists that store references.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you access an array like that, Python wraps the underlying information in a new object, so:

```
In [3]: a = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])

In [4]: a[0]
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [5]: a[0] is a[0]
Out[5]: False
```

Or perhaps visualized another way:

```
In [6]: id(a[0])
Out[6]: 140266652673680

In [7]: id(a[0])
Out[7]: 140268012281648

In [8]: id(a[0])
Out[8]: 140267734662960

In [9]: id(a[0])
Out[9]: 140266652673680
```

You shouldn't *expect* `id(a[0])` to be different. It's free to re-use the same `id` because the lifetimes of those objects are not overlapping.

Of course, whether it re-uses that ID is an implementation detail. But why did you *expect* the ID to change? It is important to understand,

```
A = [0,0,0]; a[0] = A
```

Does not in anyway *put that list in the array*. Instead, the primitive, underlying buffer is modified.

> (As far as I know, number is immutable, so when something new as a
> number is assigned, the object address should point out different
> address including the number)

There *are no python objects in your array*, you are using a `numpy.int64` dtype. This is crucial to understand.

Comment: I thought it was simple copy, so the a[0] could be changed

Comment: @4cket I don't understand what you mean. `a[0]` doesn't really create a *copy* per se. There is nothing to *copy*. The key issue you have to understand is that `numpy.ndarray` objects are object-oriented wrappers around primitive, C-like arrays/buffers